# replace tag with with a different dom element using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way we can replace an html tag with a different one using **d3.js** or just Vanilla JS?, for example to replace `<table></table>` with `<div></div>`

```html
<body>
  <div> 
    <table> ...... </table>
  </div> 
</body>
```

I have tried my implementation but it has resulted in an error. I am not sure where I did wrong. I need some advices on this

```
var customStyle = function(){
  var tbl = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + ' .crosstab-table-container table');
  tbl.attr('class','loppo');
  
  var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
  tbl.parentNode(mySpan, tbl);
}
```

I guess this code is not supported as I am doing a third party script customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about find the tags you will replace and its parent node, then remove this tag and append the other you want replace to?

```js
const table = d3.select('#table');
const parent = d3.select(table.node().parentNode);

table.remove();
parent.append('div').text('append')

//console.log(parent)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div>
11
  <table id="table"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>
</div>
```